# How would I pass an onclick value to another button?

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to accomplish is I have a data table, and there's a button for each dr. I would like to set-it-up to where when the button in each dr is clicked, it passes it's onclick function, and variable, to another button.

The button I would like to take the function out of looks like this:

```
<button onclick="buyPhone('17729198426','(772) 919-8426');" type="button">Acquire</button>
```

And the target button looks like this:

```
<button id="saveNumber" type="button" class ="viewcust_tbl_new_button" onclick="">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to your function buyPhone something like that:

```
$('#saveNumber').attr('onclick', yourFuncFromTheFirstButton);
```

Comment: Except that this question isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery can be used, but now the thing is.. Is I'm not sure if these suggestions will work. The numbers are dynamic, as well as the button's ID.

Comment: @MarcusNizza is will work nicely as you can have variable so you will get dynamic values. For example: $("#"+dynamicID).attr

Comment: @MarcusNizza - perhaps you should update your question with these new details.

Comment: I was able to solve it using the following code:

    function  buyPhone(number, friendly)
    {
        $('#aqu').show();
        $("#saveNumber").attr("onclick", "purchasePhone('" + number + "','" + friendly + "');");
        
               
    }

Comment: Great - I'm happy to hear it help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a event function from one element to another like so:

```
document.getElementById('button1').click = document.getElementById('button2').click;
```